# Get checked checkbox value by for each funtion in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not getting the checked checkbox value when using for each function of javascript. When i check a checkbox value is not coming from that function.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var coffee = document.querySelectorAll("[name = coffee]:checked");
  coffee.forEach(myfunction);
  alert(coffee);

  function myfunction(txt) {
    document.getElementById("order").value += txt;
  }
}
// To remove the last comma we can use txt.slice(0,-2). We used -2 because there are two characters ", " which is comma and space.
```

```html
<p>How would you like your coffee?</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="100">With cream<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="150">With sugar<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="200">With milk<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="250">With tea<br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Send order">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Each checkbox must have a distinct name, yours are all the same

Answer (score 2):

- Each element matching `document.querySelectorAll("[name = coffee]:checked");` is an *element*, not a number, so assigning it to the `.value` of an input will result in concatenating the string representation of the element (which is `HTMLInputElement`). That's not what you want. Access the `.value` of the input instead
- `+` will concatenate when either operand is a string, and `.value` returns a string. Cast each value to number, and *add* to a different number, then assign to the `order` element at the end:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var coffee = document.querySelectorAll("[name = coffee]:checked");
  let sum = 0;
  coffee.forEach(myfunction);
  function myfunction(input) {
    sum += Number(input.value);
  }
  document.getElementById("order").value = sum;
}
// To remove the last comma we can use txt.slice(0,-2). We used -2 because there are two characters ", " which is comma and space.
```

```html
<p>How would you like your coffee?</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="100">With cream<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="150">With sugar<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="200">With milk<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="250">With tea<br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Send order">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

More elegantly, use `.reduce` to sum up the prices, and [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) - they have far too many issues, attach listeners properly using Javascript instead:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const sum = [...document.querySelectorAll("[name = coffee]:checked")]
    .reduce((a, input) => a + Number(input.value), 0);
  document.getElementById("order").value = sum;
});
```

```html
<p>How would you like your coffee?</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="100">With cream<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="150">With sugar<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="200">With milk<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="250">With tea<br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Send order">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Even more elegantly, use labels for the `With` texts, so that clicking on that text results in toggling the associated input:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const sum = [...document.querySelectorAll("[name = coffee]:checked")]
    .reduce((a, input) => a + Number(input.value), 0);
  document.getElementById("order").value = sum;
});
```

```html
<p>How would you like your coffee?</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="100">With cream</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="150">With sugar</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="200">With milk</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="250">With tea</label><br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Send order">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You could also consider using a `change` listener so that the current sum is displayed immediately, rather than after a click.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve `checked` checkboxes values with the following

I have created a variable that is used to store the selected checkboxes values and send these values to your input box.

```js
function myFunction() {
 
        var coffee = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
          coffee[i] = $(this).val();
        });
    
   document.getElementById("order").value = coffee;

 }
 // To remove the last comma we can use txt.slice(0,-2). We used -2 because there are two characters ", " which is comma and space.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>How would you like your coffee?</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="100">With cream<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="150">With sugar<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="200">With milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="250">With tea<br>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Send order">
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="order" size="50">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>




</body>
</html>
```